# Parsing JSON in objective-c can't understand how get a parameter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, parsing

```
{"updated":1350213484,"id":"http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/feed-finder?q\u003dProva\u0026output\u003djson","title":"Risultati di feed per \"Prova\"","self":[{"href":"http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/feed-finder?q\u003dProva\u0026output\u003djson"}],"items":[{"title":"Home Page - La prova del cuoco","id":"http://www.laprovadelcuoco.rai.it/","updated":1350213485,"feed":[{"href":"http://www.laprovadelcuoco.rai.it/dl/portali/site/page/Page-ffb545b4-9e72-41e5-866f-a465588c43fa-rss.html"}],"alternate":[
{"href":"http://www.laprovadelcuoco.rai.it/","type":"text/html"}],"content":{"direction":"ltr","content":"Diventa un cuoco provetto con “La Prova del Cuoco”: le videoricette in un'  applicazione di facile e veloce consultazione per il tuo Iphone. Scopri come   acquistare ..."}},{"title":"Le prove Invalsi di matematica e italiano","id":"http://online.scuola.zanichelli.it/quartaprova/","updated":1350213486,"feed":[{"href":"http://online.scuola.zanichelli.it/quartaprova/feed/"}],"alternate":[{"href":"http://online.scuola.zanichelli.it/quartaprova/",
"type":"text/html"}],"content":{"direction":"ltr","content":"Un sito Zanichelli dedicato alle prove Invalsi di italiano e matematica:   esercitazioni, consigli, informazioni utili, novità, aggiornamenti e blog d'autore   sulle prove ..."}},{"title":"A Prova di Mamma","id":"http://www.aprovadimamma.net/","updated":1350213487,"feed":[{"href":"http://aprovadimamma.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default"}],"alternate":[{"href":"http://www.aprovadimamma.net/","type":"text/html"}],"content":{"direction":"ltr",
"content":"recensioni, guide ed opinioni sui prodotti per bambini. web | www.  \u003ca href\u003d\"http://aprovadimamma.net\"\u003eaprovadimamma.net\u003c/a\u003e email | aprovadimamma -at- \u003ca href\u003d\"http://gmail.com\"\u003egmail.com\u003c/a\u003e. 2011 A Prova di   Mamma è un ..."}},{"title":"prova - Wiktionary","id":"http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prova","updated":1350213488,"feed":[{"href":"http://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title\u003dSpecial:RecentChanges\u0026feed\u003datom"}],"alternate":[
{"href":"http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prova","type":"text/html"}],"content":{"direction":"ltr","content":"prova. Definition from Wiktionary, the free dictionary. Jump to: navigation, search.   See also pröva, and próva. Contents. 1 Catalan. 1.1 Noun; 1.2 Verb. 2 Italian ..."}},{"title":"Prova a prendermi - MYmovies","id":"http://www.mymovies.it/dizionario/recensione.asp?id\u003d34298","updated":1350213489,"feed":[{"href":"http://www.mymovies.it/cinema/xml/rss/"}],"alternate":[{"href":"http://www.mymovies.it/dizionario/recensione.asp?id\u003d34298",
"type":"text/html"}],"content":{"direction":"ltr","content":"Un film di Steven Spielberg con Leonardo DiCaprio, Tom Hanks, Christopher   Walken, Martin Sheen. Spielberg decide di divertire e divertirsi, con un cast ..."}},{"title":"Prova a incastrarmi - MYmovies","id":"http://www.mymovies.it/dizionario/recensione.asp?id\u003d35955","updated":1350213490,"feed":[{"href":"http://www.mymovies.it/cinema/xml/rss/"}],"alternate":[{"href":"http://www.mymovies.it/dizionario/recensione.asp?id\u003d35955",
"type":"text/html"}],"content":{"direction":"ltr","content":"Un film di Sidney Lumet con Vin Diesel, Peter Dinklage, Linus Roache, Ron   Silver. Il processo per mafia più lungo della storia degli Usa nelle mani di Lumet   e ..."}},{"title":"Impariamo.info","id":"http://www.impariamo.info/","updated":1350213491,"feed":[{"href":"http://www.impariamo.info/feeds/posts/default"}],"alternate":[{"href":"http://www.impariamo.info/","type":"text/html"}],"content":{"direction":"ltr","content":"Impariamo.info. Prova il tuo italiano. Pages. Home · Cultura · Chat ... Prove di   ascolto. Dettati · Livello A2 · Livello B1 · Livello B2. Giochi. Acrostici · Anagrammi ..."
}},{"title":"Schede informative prova scritta di Ateneo - Ca' Foscari","id":"http://www.unive.it/nqcontent.cfm?a_id\u003d134832","updated":1350213492,"feed":[{"href":"http://www.unive.it/phpapps/rss/eventi_rss.php"}],"alternate":[{"href":"http://www.unive.it/nqcontent.cfm?a_id\u003d134832","type":"text/html"}],"content":{"direction":"ltr","content":"Di seguito sono pubblicate le sedi delle prove scritte di Ateneo e, in allegato, ...   La prova scritta si svolgerà giovedì 30 agosto alle ore 16.00 presso il Polo di San ..."
}},{"title":"Prova d'autore","id":"http://www.osservatorionline.it/page/459/prova-dautore-leggere-per-scrivere","updated":1350213493,"feed":[{"href":"http://www.osservatorionline.it/page/459/rss-news.php?lang\u003dit"}],"alternate":[{"href":"http://www.osservatorionline.it/page/459/prova-dautore-leggere-per-scrivere","type":"text/html"}],"content":{"direction":"ltr","content":"Prova d'autore: leggere per scrivere. Edizione 2012/2013. Per l'anno scolastico   2012-2013 l'Osservatorio Permanente Giovani-Editori e la Fondazione Achille e ..."
}},{"title":"Maturità, la terza prova scritta ma potrebbe essere l'ultima volta ...","id":"http://www.repubblica.it/scuola/2012/06/24/news/terza_prova_maturita-37857437/","updated":1350213494,"feed":[{"href":"http://www.repubblica.it/rss/homepage/rss2.0.xml"}],"alternate":[{"href":"http://www.repubblica.it/scuola/2012/06/24/news/terza_prova_maturita-37857437/","type":"text/html"}],"content":{"direction":"ltr","content":"24 giu 2012 ... Predisposta la mattina stessa dalle commissioni, comporta spesso molte difficoltà   per gli studenti. Subito dopo inizia la correzione degli ..."
}}]}
```

How can I parse it?

I'm doing

```
NSArray* title = [(NSDictionary*)[daParsare JSONValue] objectForKey:@"title"];
NSLog(title);
```

I get `Risultati di feed per \"Prova\`

but what I want are all "title" inside the "items" and the "feed" parameter... I want to store they in one array
How can I do?

******* EDIT ********

Ok but when I try to get the feed url I get a SIGABRT error

```
NSDictionary *element=[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
NSString *title = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[element objectForKey:@"title"]]; 
NSString *summary = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[element valueForKeyPath:@"feed.href"]]; cell.textLabel.numberOfLines=3; 
cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]; 
cell.textLabel.text = title; 
cell.detailTextLabel.text = summary; 
cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines=5; 
[title release]; 
[summary release];
```

If I try to NSLog the feed url in the loop cycle it was null!

last question in this case how can I get the content? it is in a content key inside another content key! :S

```
That's an example 
"title":"Home Page - La prova del cuoco",
"id":"http://www.laprovadelcuoco.rai.it/",
"updated":1350213485,
"feed":[
{
"href":"http://www.laprovadelcuoco.rai.it/dl/portali/site/page/Page-ffb545b4-9e72-41e5-866f-a465588c43fa-rss.html"
}
],
```

feed is different from title...

Comment: Peel the onion, one layer at a time.

Comment: The JSON that you posted is good for computers, but the block is too large too be understood by an average human without additional formatting. Please re-format the block to make the level at which other `title`s appear be more visible.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight -- Aw, you can just copy/paste into http://json.parser.online.fr/ and see it.  Better than dealing with a hacked-up partial.

Comment: Each pair of `{}` or `[]` is a "layer of the onion".  You take off one layer at a time, then look at what's left (which still looks like an onion).  Repeat the procedure until you get to the data you want.  Ie, don't be overwhelmed by the whole wad of data, just consider one simple step at a time.

Comment: (Note that you can use `isKindOfClass` to determine what object type is returned from an `objectForKey` or `objectAtIndex` call, so you can check to be sure you got the type you expected at each step a long the way.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you get the array for key "items". Using the below code I get the following output:

Code:

```
NSArray *itemsDic=[jsonParsedObj objectForKey:@"items"];
NSArray *titles=[itemsDic valueForKey:@"title"];
```

To get the contents from "items" , use the following code

```
NSArray *contents=[itemsDic valueForKeyPath:@"content.content"];
```

Output:

(
Home Page - La prova del cuoco,

Le prove Invalsi di matematica e italiano,

A Prova di Mamma,

prova - Wiktionary,

Prova a prendermi - MYmovies,

Prova a incastrarmi - MYmovies,

Impariamo.info,

Schede informative prova scritta di Ateneo - Ca' Foscari,

Prova d'autore,

Maturità, la terza prova scritta ma potrebbe essere l'ultima volta ...
)

Comment: @UsiUsi edited the code on your request , to retrieve content from items.

Answer (score 4):

In the given example you will look for the first object containing the key "title". Which in the JSON is located at the first level of data.

In order to get the value for the "items" you first need to parse that level of data then fetch the values you are interested in.

The example below first fetches the items from the root level then goes through each of the keys, finding the title and the feed value.

Hope this helps!

```
NSArray *items = [[daParsare JSONValue] objectForKey:@"items"];
for (NSDictionary *item in items) {
    NSString *title = [item objectForKey:@"title"];
    NSString *feed = [item valueForKeyPath:@"feed.href"];
}
```

Comment: Updated with more explanation.

Comment: Thanks; your post was listed in the 'low quality' review queue because you post only contained code. Thanks for making your answer, and thus Stack Overflow, more helpful!

Comment: Ok but when I try to get the feed url I get a SIGABRT error     NSDictionary *element=[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    NSString *title = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[element objectForKey:@"title"]];
    NSString *summary = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[element valueForKeyPath:@"feed.href"]];
    
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines=3;
    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
    cell.textLabel.text = title;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = summary;
    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines=5;
    [title release];
    [summary release];

Comment: I get error when I try to assign summary to the detailTextLabel

Comment: last question in this case how can I get the content? it is in a content key inside another content key! :S